# Time complexity regarding O(LogN)

Tags: python, time-complexity

Let's say we have the following code.

```
def problem(n):
  list = []
  for i in range(n):
    list.append(i)
    length = len(list) 
  return list
```

The program has time complexity of `O(n)` if we don't calculate `len(list)`. But if we do, will the time complexity be `O(n * log(n))` or `O(n^2)`? .

Comment: `len(list)` is O(1).

Comment: Why on earth would it be O(n log n) or O(n^2)? Even if `len` was not O(1), the "worst implementation possible" would still be at most O(n)...

Answer (score 1):

No, the len() function has constant time in python and it is not dependent on the length of the element, your time complexity for the above code would remain O(N) governed by your `for i in range(n)` loop. [Here is the time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for many CPython functions, like len()! (Get Length in table)